# Последний слог слов продажа, кража, пряжа, поклажа

Tags: этимология, морфемный-разбор

Откуда в слове продажа взялся последний слог *"жа"*?

По аналогии с представленными ниже группами слов должно же вроде было получиться нечто вроде *"прожа"*?

*краду кража;
пряду пряжа; 
покладаю поклажа; 
пропадаю пропажа; 
неведаю невежа;
продаю "прожа"?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) По словарю Тихонова: *красть — кража, прясть — пряжа, класть — поклажа, пропасть — пропажа*.

Везде указано **чередование С/Ж,** суффикс нулевой. В Сети можно встретить разборы, где выделяется суффикс Ж (прясть — пря/ж/а).

2) Здесь у Тихонова указан **суффикс Ж**: *продать — прода/ж/а.*

3) В словах *невежа, невежда* формант **Ж и ЖД входит в состав корня**.

Comment: По п.2). Слово *продажа* этимологически происходить от **про** и **дать**. И вот любопытно, есть ли связь между буквами **ж** в словах **продажа** и **даждь**. Или это тот же суффикс?

Comment: Дать или продать - не имеет значения, эти слова отличаются от предыдущей группы (нет чередования С/Ж). А с суффиксом  Ж всё очень неясно.

Comment: Да, я по п.1) всё понял, меня именно суффикс интересовал. Спасибо, буду знать, что с ним сложности, а то я подумал, что это у меня пробел.

Comment: Раньше существовала форма _дасть_, в ней есть чередование.